# Error while trying to add AndEngine to my example project

Tags: java, android, andengine

I've downloaded the latest AndEngine from Nicolas on his Github repo. Made all the extensions compile on my workspace, everything was okay.

Created a project to start testing the Engine, but whenever I go to my example project properties > Android and try to add AndEngine or any of its extensions, there's a green tick... so I accept when I apply the changes, but when I open the Android configuration again and see the library imports, there's a red "X" on every import, like it failed.

Here's the screenshot:

> [image]

Does anyone has encountered this problem before? How do I solve it?

Comment: try to put library in your libs folder.

Comment: try close project testingAND and reopen it ...

Comment: closing and reopening it didn't make the trick :( @wqrahd how am i supposed to do that? Tried doing a "Build Path > Link source" but i believe that's not the way to do it properly

Comment: but it sometimes work.

Comment: lol thanks to the guy that posted before, my project worked lol, but the comment was deleted, now it's working. I've added the andengine.jar into my lib project. But... what if i want to add extensions to the project?

Comment: Thanks guys, found the issue, look at my answer. Thanks for caring anyway :')

Answer (score 3):

No worries, made it work thanks to a guy from this forum

http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/getting-started-with-andengine-t4858-180.html

Going to quote what he said, it really worked:

> Hey, look, I can contribute! (Sorry, I'm just excited to be able to
>   add something here)
>
> I had this same issue and resolved it by moving the libraries
>   (AndEngine, etc.) into my Eclipse workspace.
>
> For instance, I originally had all my AndEngine files in C:\Users[my
>   user name]\git\AndEngine\ and encountered the same errors you
>   describe. After some Googling, I found that I had to move the
>   AndEngine library from .../git/ to my eclipse workspace, which is
>   located at F:\android-workspace
>
> So in the end my project's files were located at:
>   F:\android-workspace[project_name]
>
> And the AndEngine files were located at:
>   F:\android-workspace\AndEngine
>
> Be sure to re-link the library to your project after moving it. Also,
>   I apologize for my verboseness, I just wanted to be clear.